# Prevent answer from rounding

Tags: ruby, math

The title alone has [many answers](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=prevent%20ruby%20from%20rounding&oq=prevent%20ruby%20from%20rounding&aqs=chrome..69i57.366j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) for different languages but I'm having a weird behavior. I get correct figures in the rails console but not so with Rails.

**Console:**

```
a = -42.57
b = -43.47
a - b = 0.8999999999999986
```

Rails' answer is `1.0`. This slight error makes a huge difference in my application.

```
answer = (a-b)
answer < 1 ? 'do something' : 'do other thing'
```

I need the exact calculation. Why it's not so in Rails controller but correct in the console? There's no database involved, just basic math in a method.

**Controller**

```
def step_3  
 a = 112.53 - 155
 b = 112.53 - 156
 a - b
end
```

Comment: Can you post the code of the controller?

Comment: @Pavan Ive updated the post

Comment: just a tip. IF youre dealing with MONEY. you should  never use floats. Simply operate on cents or whatever is the smallest denominator and work with integers. This way you never have to worry about this.

Comment: @LukaszMuzyka Ive updated the post again. But look at my last edit. Still not makings sense. That's just basic math.

Comment: @Sylar - sure its a simple math, but this is known behavior of float in any computer language.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems

Comment: @LukaszMuzyka Yes. Thanks for that.

Comment: @Sylar your values differ: you have `a = -42.47` in your controller vs. `a = -42.57` in your console code.

Comment: @Stefan im on mobile so MAYBE typo. Ill confirm later when laptop has power

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a Rails problem. You are using an inappropriate data type.

If you need precise results, you could do it like this:

```
require 'bigdecimal'

a=BigDecimal.new('-42.57')
b=BigDecimal.new('43.47')
c=a-b
puts(c.to_s('F')) # prints -86.04
```